# Amazon EC2 - Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (JSON)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, amazon-ec2, bundle

I just deployed some new code (only some text update in views) and while processing the command **cap deploy**, I got following error message:

```
 ** [out :: IP] Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 ** [out :: IP]
 ** [out :: IP] /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
 ** [out :: IP] creating Makefile
 ** [out :: IP]
 ** [out :: IP] make "DESTDIR="
 ** [out :: IP]
 ** [out :: IP] Gem files will remain installed in /home/deployer/fileto/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
 ** [out :: IP] Results logged to /home/deployer/appname/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
 ** [out :: IP] An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
 ** [out :: IP] Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

It just appeared today, I didn't do anything with the app for like 2 weeks. I've tried add the **json** gem to the Gemfile, but it didn't help - still the same error.

What is the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, but since I got here with Google, someone else might as well:

You need to reinstall command line tools. I am assuming you upgraded to Mavericks? It sorta wiped out CLI from xcode. You now have to actually go to the Apple developer site and download CL Tool for Mavericks:
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=for%20Xcode%20-#

After installing, a bundle should work.

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge. this thing may occur due to different reasons,

```
1) The gem version you are using or their dependency are not supported with other gem version or the ruby version you are using.
2) there is not enough permission to install the gem
3) the gem version is not present in the repository.
```

I am sorry that i can not give you the exact solution but you can check this option and try accordingly .

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the mystery of development to EC2.

I solved this issue by logging to the EC2 server and ran there following command:

```
sudo gem install json
```

Afterwards I was able to deploy the app properly. However, I still don't understand why or where from has this issue occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and perhaps it could be the new version of the JSON gem. I added this line to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'json', '1.8.0'
```

(the PREVIOUS version of the JSON gem)

Then run: `bundle update` in order to overwrite the newer version of the JSON gem.

I don't know what the problem with the newer version of the gem is, but it came out on October 17, and if you didn't have this problem before, perhaps it's the updated gem...?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running RVM, then in addition to installing the command-line tools for Mavericks, as in the answer provided by @mike-manfrin, you may also need to do the following:

- Update RVM

`rvm get latest`

- Reinstall the ruby that your project or gemset is using

`rvm reinstall <ruby-version>`

Use `rvm list` if you're unsure which ruby you're currently using. After these two steps, I found that I could then bundle the project and that the json gem installed correctly.